# Create new column values by grep on another column, using a vector of patterns

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` and I want to search in one column `Name` in order to create a new value in the other column that has the search pattern in it. I can get this to work one by one, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this more elegantly. Could I make a vector `intensities = c("1mW", "5mW", and "10mW")` of patterns and then have another vector of replacements? (the same values in this case).

```
Name    Intensity
file-1mW    1mW
file-1mW    1mW
file-5mW    5mW
file-10mW   10mW
file-1mW    1mW
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_extract` for this. The regular expression `\w+$` will take the last *word* from the string, which in this case is delimited by the "-" character.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- read.table(text = "
  Name    Intensity
  file-1mW    1mW
  file-1mW    1mW
  file-5mW    5mW
  file-10mW   10mW
  file-1mW    1mW" , header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df %>% mutate(new = str_extract(Name, "\\w+$"))

#        Name Intensity  new
# 1  file-1mW       1mW  1mW
# 2  file-1mW       1mW  1mW
# 3  file-5mW       5mW  5mW
# 4 file-10mW      10mW 10mW
# 5  file-1mW       1mW  1mW
```

An alternate approach could be to split the string using the dash and taking the second element.

```
df %>% mutate(new = str_split(Name, "-")[[1]][2])

df %>% mutate(new = strsplit(Name, "-")[[1]][2]) # the base option
```

Which produces the same result.

Comment: base R: `sub(".*?-","",df$Name)`

Comment: @Onyambu, yes, I included the approaches to extract and split. Using sub to cut is equally valid and useful. You can always add as an answer